# remove item from list, knockout.js

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

Please see code (Using knockout.js over ASP MVC 3):

```
self.tags = ko.utils.arrayMap(@Html.Raw(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model.Tags)), function(tag) {
                return {
                    label: tag.Name,
                    value: tag.id
                };
        });

self.addTag = function(event, ui){
            $(event.target).val("");

            var tag = ui.item.label;
            var id = ui.item.value;

            self.selectedTags.push("id: " + id + ", Name: " + tag);
            //Delete selected tag here from list
            return false;
        }
```

The question is, how can I remove from tags? (I tried using remove(), I encounter an error. But when I try pop(), its successful)

Comment: If `.pop()` works, why not use it?

Comment: .pop() only gets the last item you entered right? i want to be able to delete any item in the array.

Comment: I see, your right, in that case pop wouldn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your tags array is normal array, not observable array, it will have no remove method.

Knockout has helper for normal arrays

```
ko.utils.arrayRemoveItem(array, itemToRemove)
```

or you can use splice (actually ko.utils.arrayRemoveItem uses splice)

Answer (score 1):

Normally you can remove an item from a javascript array with splice.

Pop will not work as it only removes the last inserted value.

var a = [1,2,3]
a.splice(1,1); # remove one element at position 1 => [1,3]

you can use this with knockout if you want.

knockout also has some api's like array.remove(function(a){ return a.id === 1; }) that returns all elements that have the id 1.

EDIT:
As an example you can look at this JsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Ng39n/

Comment: I still get a 'Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method' when using array.remove(function(a){ return a.id === 1; }); is there any relation to me using ko.utils.arrayMap?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a function to your view model, removeTag, like the following:

```
self.removeTag = function(tag) { self.tags.remove(tag); })
```